# cc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64' when cross compile rust app to linux x86 in mac book pro with M1 chip

Tags: docker, rust, cross-compiling

I am tried to build the rust app to docker `Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086` image in mac book pro with M1 chip, this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.54-bullseye as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

this is the `main.rs`:

```
fn main() {
    print!("hello world");
}
```

and this is the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "alt-server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
```

when I build the docker file using this command:

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t="reddwarf-pro/alt-server:v1.0.0" .
```

shows error like this:

```
+ docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t=reddwarf-pro/alt-server:v1.0.0 .
[+] Building 16.3s (12/17)                                                                                                                                                      
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 783B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for gcr.io/distroless/static-debian11:latest                                                                                                  1.7s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/rust:1.54-bullseye                                                                                                     15.4s
 => [builder 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/rust:1.54-bullseye@sha256:ced8370c54cf6cd22a6bb8f8fa0ca1002777b18b3269031ed174022a334484f2                                        0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/6] FROM gcr.io/distroless/static-debian11@sha256:7198a357ff3a8ef750b041324873960cf2153c11cc50abb9d8d5f8bb089f6b4e                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                          0.2s
 => => transferring context: 513.61kB                                                                                                                                      0.2s
 => CACHED [builder 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 3/6] COPY . /app                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 4/6] RUN rustup default stable                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [builder 5/6] RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl                                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [builder 6/6] RUN RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl                                                            0.6s
------                                                                                                                                                                          
 > [builder 6/6] RUN RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl:                                                                       
#13 0.504    Compiling alt-server v0.1.0 (/app)                                                                                                                                 
#13 0.616 error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1                                                                                                                       
#13 0.616   |                                                                                                                                                                   
#13 0.616   = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/self-contained:/usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "-m64" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/rcrt1.o" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crti.o" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtbeginS.o" "/tmp/rustcEeYC4h/symbols.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-a657a1097a5b4a9d.alt_server.474401a8-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-a657a1097a5b4a9d.alt_server.474401a8-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-a657a1097a5b4a9d.alt_server.474401a8-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-a657a1097a5b4a9d.1b0krt6u1v81dfz8.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps" "-L" "/app/target/release/deps" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libstd-a9e9fdf6bd876a9c.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libpanic_unwind-9916a49f714358b5.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libobject-7c95a8771a218fe4.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libmemchr-3c65c0c83cf6c411.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libaddr2line-ce480adcfb4c499a.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libgimli-9bcfb39999c11ef2.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_demangle-9bf53e18f8bef2e1.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libstd_detect-9a4ef6243d492215.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libhashbrown-529ae92fb3c6744a.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libminiz_oxide-78298b69f5703e62.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libadler-ade0c67529f3c0af.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-84e233915e97cb9e.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libunwind-7160ae02eff3b4cd.rlib" "-lunwind" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcfg_if-edfb0a83a752acf9.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liblibc-874d27a1db360080.rlib" "-lc" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liballoc-2c943eba15e5e78b.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-c29380f4766b919c.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcore-81996ce6d2f33980.rlib" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcompiler_builtins-1fcb8ee8de54bbff.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-nostartfiles" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-L" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained" "-o" "/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/alt_server-a657a1097a5b4a9d" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-static-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs" "-s" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtendS.o" "/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtn.o"
#13 0.616   = note: cc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-m64'
#13 0.616           
#13 0.616 
#13 0.625 error: could not compile `alt-server` (bin "alt-server") due to previous error
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]: exit code: 101
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? is it possible to build this docker image with M1 chip mac book pro? I am learning with the rust cross compile.

Comment: Specifying aarch64 (or using a copy of gcc built with that as the only target) is enough to indicate that you want a 64-bit build to gcc; you don't need to pass `-m64` in addition.